# Lookup value in R dataframe, as simple as possible

Tags: r, merge, lookup

I have this data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c("a","b","c"))
```

so I need to get the value from column `y` linked to `x==2`. I´ve seen many users use `merge()`, but is there another way to do that in a simple way, with just one function?

Something like `lookup(df$x, x==2)` to get value "b"

Comment: You say *"as simply as possible"*, but what value(s) do you want returned if there are multiple rows matching `x==2`? or no rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, `merge` is a better way when you have two dataframes to combine with many columns.

Here you can use `match`:

```
df$y[match(2, df$x)]
#[1] "b"
```

Or :

```
df$y[df$x == 2]
```

Comment: @Angelo Note that these two good suggestions behave differently when there are no matches (returning NA vs. an empty vector), and also when there are multiple matches (returning the first match vs. all the matches).

Answer (score 0):

In case `df$x` is a sequence like `1:3` you can use `[]` directly:

```
df$y[2]
#[1] "b"
```

or in case `df$x` is a positive integer with gaps:

```
lookup <- NA
lookup[df$x] <- df$y
lookup[2]
#[1] "b"
```

or in case `df$x` can be used as `character`

```
lookup <- setNames(df$y, df$x)
lookup["2"]
#  2 
#"b"
```

or using an `environment` to speed up the search by using it's hash:

```
lookup <- list2env(as.list(setNames(df$y, df$x)))
lookup$"2"
#[1] "b"
```